# Vagrant up error

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I executed `vagrant up`, but it fails and this is the error:

> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
>   Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```

Stdout from the command:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fakeroot linux-headers-3.2.0-23 make patch
Suggested packages:
  make-doc diffutils-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot linux-headers-3.2.0-23 linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic make
  patch
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 185 not upgraded.
Need to get 272 kB/12.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 68.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main make amd64 3.81-8.1ubuntu1.1 [119 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main patch amd64 2.6.1-3ubuntu0.1 [80.0 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main patch amd64 2.6.1-3ubuntu0.1 [80.0 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.6 [73.3 kB]
Fetched 271 kB in 1min 37s (2,791 B/s)
```

Stderr from the command:

```
stdin: is not a tty
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_3.81-8.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/patch/patch_2.6.1-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: How are you running that command from your Vagrantfile? Shell provisioner?

Comment: self explanatory _maybe run apt-get update_ and that before you run `apt-get install -y linux-headers-``uname -r`` dkms`

Comment: Having the same problem in vagrant using debian/buster64 with no provisioning at all just Vagrantfile.